# How to write my dockerfile in order to add my init.sql file to docker mysql container

Tags: docker

My init.sql contain the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Products;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql), the MySQL will look for init files under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  upon container startup, so you can try adding something like

```
COPY /path/to/your/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

to your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

If the script just contains to create DB as you mentioned in the question then you do need anything just pass the DB name as ENV and MySQL container will create one.

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: products

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```